# How can I pass a table or table-valued parameter from SQL2008 to Oracle Procedure via Linked Server?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, t-sql, plsql, sys-refcursor

I have an oracle stored procedure that accepts a value list through ref cursor.  This oracle database is set up as a Linked Server in a separate SQL Server 2008 instance.

How can I use this procedure from within SQL, passing a table, rows, or a table-valued parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked long ago, but for people Googling and come across this post...

It sounds like you need to do a openquery.

This basically sends the 'select...' part (could be a stored procedure exec) command to the linked server and waits for the response.

SELECT *  FROM  OPENQUERY(Your_Linked_Server_Name ,  'select * from TableName where RecordID = 4')